# Why UIBarButtonItem is not visible to some of user's iPhones?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, uinavigationitem

I have released one app with RightBarItem feature in it. I have tested with some of iPhone's with latest and old iOS(versions includes iOS 9, iOS 10 and iOS 11). I can see the Right item to all the iPhone which I have tested. But some of user have raised an issue saying, that they are not able to see the right item in app.

**Code snippet:**

```
{
  UIBarButtonItem *trashBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash
                                                                             target: self
                                                                       action: @selector(deleteHandler)];  
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = trashBtn;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: if you released wit right Button feature only, how would you see left bar button then? Or you mean back button?

Comment: Sorry, check my latest edit. User not able to see my RightButton only.